# How to extend Laptop screen with a monitor?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, external-display

I am using a laptop and I tried to extend laptop screen with a monitor using HDMI cable. However, when I extend the monitor via Display Settings, the mouse can only be active one of the screen; laptop or monitor. However, I simply want to extend the laptop monitor as I had done before using 2 monitor and 1 workstation. For example I want to open VSCode on monitor and Docker Desktop on laptop screen. I look at [How to set up and use multiple monitors in Windows](https://support.lenovo.com/tr/en/solutions/ht004036-how-to-set-up-and-use-multiple-monitors-in-windows) page, but it is for 2 monitors I think.

Is it possible to perform such a kind of scenario that I mentioned above?

Comment: Does anybody else have not ever used this feature?

Comment: make sure that the settings are correct. you may have your second screen on your right, but if the settings are set so that your OS think's it's on the left, you have tomove your cursor left to get it on the other screen

Comment: Be patient Jasmine. This is not a situation where someone can look over your shoulder. It does work on my laptop, and I expect yours. JoSSte's comment may be exactly the situation.

Comment: @JoSSte **Exactly!..** Many thanks. But is it possible to make the monitor screen as primary screen? Because the taskbar on the main screen is exactşy what I want (the icons are tiled) whereas on the secondary screen it is displayed as a small icon (I mean opened app's icons). Any idea?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon What about setting monitor screen as a main screen?

Comment: select the screen and look at the options - te option should be there

Comment: On my laptop, I can set either as the main display.

Comment: @JoSSte you can switch monitors as primary and secondary. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_continuum/how-to-make-external-monitor-as-primary-monitor/d3aa456d-4c6d-4798-9ab4-1efc8d6cda6c

Comment: Thanks a lot, you right it seems to be very easy. I already tried that option but **"Make this my main display" is disabled** even I reinstall the graphic driver. I also try by installing Lenovo Smart Display Applications for Windows 10, but there is not such a kind of option. Some workarounds do not seem to be working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [web link you provided](https://support.lenovo.com/tr/en/solutions/ht004036-how-to-set-up-and-use-multiple-monitors-in-windows) gives you the answer to what you need.

In the settings they point to, there is

> - PC screen only — Only the primary monitor (1) is used
> - Duplicate — Secondary monitor shows duplicate desktop
> - Extend — Both monitors combine to offer an extended desktop
> - Second screen only — Only the secondary monitor is used

In **extend** mode you can have what you want.

When you open VSCode and Docker Desktop, they may initially open on your laptop screen, but if you drag the Docker Desktop window off the screen you should find it appears on your second screen.

That's because the 2nd screen is extending your desktop space and acting like the 2nd half of your desktop.

If you wish to change which monitor is the primary monitor, the answer in https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_continuum/how-to-make-external-monitor-as-primary-monitor/d3aa456d-4c6d-4798-9ab4-1efc8d6cda6c should help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanations. Due to the position of laptop and monitor, the right and left screens are mixed and I thought as if was not working : ) Here is a little problem: The main screen is laptop screen and I cannot make my monitor screen as main screen. I mean that there is only icons are shown on the secondary screen whereas on the main screen, it is tiled. So, **is it possible to make monitor screen as primary when extending with laptop or PC?**

Comment: By the way I cannot vote up as I need an extra 4 points :( If you vote up the question, I can vote up answer.

Comment: @Jasmine - I have already upvoted your question so unfortunately you need to wait for another upvote. If you feel my answer is what you needed to sort your problem you can 'accept' the answer by clicking the tick under the vote buttons. This will give you 2 rep points. You get 2 rep points every time you accept and answer. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_continuum/how-to-make-external-monitor-as-primary-monitor/d3aa456d-4c6d-4798-9ab4-1efc8d6cda6c should help switch primary monitors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will select of course but the problem is not solved yet after already applying the suggestions before.

Comment: You right it seems to be very easy. I already tried that option but **"Make this my main display" is disabled** even I reinstall the graphic driver. I also try by installing Lenovo Smart Display Applications for Windows 10, but there is not such a kind of option. Some workarounds do not seem to be working :(